# Which version iOS, Android and Windows devices should I use for testing my Xamarin app?

Tags: mobile, xamarin, smartphone

I'm dabbling in Xamarin-based apps. I want to test my stuff on real iOS, Android and Windows devices.

(I'll use the emulators and "test cloud", but I also want to test physically. Just one device for each platform, don't care about resolution, etc.)

As of this year - 2016 - what is the minimum version I should target for each OS when I'm buying these three devices?

I won't buy the latest and greatest of each, so my fear is that I'll buy devices which are outdated. I just want old/cheap devices for my test bed, but they must be new enough to work with Xamarin.

Comment: PS [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601005/which-android-device-should-i-buy-for-testing-apps) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352270/which-ios-devices-should-we-have-for-reasonable-functionality-and-performance-te) are way too old to be of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of my clients want their mobile apps to support current and two prior major versions of OS, e.g. at the moment iOS 9, 8, 7 and support Android 6, 5, 4(.1.1). Using Xamarin for about two years now have had no problems in achieving this. I keep a 2012 Motorola Droid Razr HD running Android 4.1.1, a 2013 Nexus 7 running Android 6, an iPad 2, an iPhone 6, an iPod Touch. Less variation in capabilities and behaviors on the Apple side makes things easier there. Your idea of having a small group of devices has served me well.

Comment: I know Windows has negligible market share, but what would you recommend on that front? 8.1 and 10?

Comment: We usually target .NET 4.5, Windows 8, and WP 8.1 for PCL, but have yet to find a client who wants a Windows mobile app.

Comment: Version-2 is a great idea. Thanks.